# How to see the complete list of issues of github's static analysis?

Tags: github, sonarqube

I am using "pullerquest" in github to comment on examination after examination. It generates comments like this one:

[image]

Here, I can only see the top ten of issues.

How can I see all of the issues? Is there a link to the complete list of files?

Comment: Per [GitHub Plugin documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) , are you using _sonar.github.disableInlineComments_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the [current version](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) (1.4.1),
the maximum number of issues to display in that list is hardcoded at 10,
by the [MAX_GLOBAL_ISSUES](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/blob/b6215b91424cf376e5ba0facc29ab2d67ddf4561/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/github/GitHubPluginConfiguration.java#L46) constant in the source code.
If you want to know more details, here's how the plugin operates:

- The `PullRequestIssuePostJob` class creates an instance of `GlobalReport` [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/blob/b6215b91424cf376e5ba0facc29ab2d67ddf4561/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/github/PullRequestIssuePostJob.java#L64), calling [this constructor](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/blob/b6215b91424cf376e5ba0facc29ab2d67ddf4561/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/github/GlobalReport.java#L35), which uses the `MAX_GLOBAL_ISSUES` constant as the default maximum.
- `PullRequestIssuePostJob` will process each issue, eventually ending up in [`GlobalReport.process`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/blob/b6215b91424cf376e5ba0facc29ab2d67ddf4561/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/github/GlobalReport.java#L159) method, where a conditional statement decides to register the issue if we are under the maximum, otherwise simply count it.

If you really want to see all issues, you could fork the code and change the constant to a higher number on [this line](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/blob/b6215b91424cf376e5ba0facc29ab2d67ddf4561/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/github/GitHubPluginConfiguration.java#L46).

As [@JulienH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534773/julien-h-sonarsource-team) pointed out in a comment, the size of GithHub comments is limited, so it is not possible to display an unlimited number of issues. This is why the cap on the number of issues displayed is necessary.

Comment: Note that size of GithHub comments is limited, so it is not possible to display an unlimited number of issues, without getting errors.

Comment: Thanks @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam for the clarification